# SoapUI (Pro) > DataDriven > Message Content Assertion - How to handle decimal values

Tags: soapui, assertion, ready-api, data-driven

I am using ReadyAPI(SoapUI Pro) for testing of a RestAPI. As Test Data Im using DataSource (DataDriven), where i am giving the Inputs (API Input) from excel. And to test the API response i am comparing the Output from Excel (Expected results are already in excel). For that I am using  Message Content Assertion (as its easy and im not much technical). 
Now problem is, In excel Expected Output is say 10.0 but when i use this excel field for assertion in SoapUI (Pro) it reads 10.0 > 10. But from API Response value is 10.0. So Assertion failed. I tried to handle it in excel but no luck.

So can at SoapUI level we can handle it in Assertion? If its not possible using Message Content Assertion, then is it possible with JsonPath Existence Match ( I have not much knowledge of Json)

Comment: hi, you probably have a problem of data type, ie. data from excel may be String and data from the response is probably float or double. what you could try is, when you add assertion on the response, use 'add assertion for existence with script' and, in your script get the data type by doing <my-value>.getClass(). You'll probably see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the Message Content Assertion always looks for strings. So your "10.0" will be treated as a string. The content from your input file, may not be treated the same way.

Another variant on the problem, could be your input file stating "10.0" as the expected value, but you receive "10,0" from the response.

You can probably fix this in several ways. I assume your Message Content Assertion contains a variable, that refers to your datasource something like ${DataSource#ColumnName} ?
Be careful with that! If you get a long response, your assertion will be positive, if that value is to be found *anywhere* inside your response. You may end up with a false positive. 10.0 could be a part of something like a timestamp, which is not an uncommon type of data to get in a webservice response.

I think I would opt to change your Message Content Assertion with a Script Assertion, and insert something like this:

```
// This should be adjusted to match your 
// DataSource name and correct column name
def value1 = context.expand( '${DataSource#value}' )

// Now we need to make sure, that no matter if you 
// receive a number in the format 10.0 or 10,0
// we convert it to one and same thing.
value1 = value1.replace(",",".")

// And in case the 10.0 is being returned as 10
// we need to manually add the .0
if (value1.indexOf(".")==-1) {
    value1 = value1.concat(".0")
}

// Now retrieve the value from the response
// You can replace this line, by rightclicking
// inside the script, and choose Get Data
def value2 = context.expand( '${TestStepName#Response#value}' )

assert value1==value2
```

Now you will only check if that particular XML entity has the expected value. This will significantly reduce your risk of a false positive.

Some adjustment will be required, to make it suit your needs.

This manner of comparison, will be subject to break, if a minor change like a change in namespaces occurs. You can improve on it by using XmlSlurper. But I will leave that out for now. Get back and ask about that, once you get there. :-)